# Magento 2 grunt exec does not actually create symlinks

Tags: magento2, less-css, magento2.1.0

I am following:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_prereq

it says `grunt exec:<theme>` does:

`Republishes symlinks to the source files to the pub/static/frontend/Vendor/default/<locale> directory.`

But that does not seem to happen!

`pub/static/frontend/Vendor/default/de_DE/css/source` contains regular files where I would expect symlinks to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default`

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**edit** I am just having this s ame problem again with Magento 2.1 - even if the patch of issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1619 should already be contained in Magento 2.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Remove Cache
2. Clean theme by the command: `grunt clean`
3. Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege.
4. Run the command: `grunt exec:yourthemename`
5. Run the command: `grunt less:yourthemename`
6. Run the command: `grunt watch`

***Edit Alex***: Basically working and the right solution, but with the limitations of https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6367

Comment: I don't think running grunt exec / less etc. as admin is a good idea. And I think it is a Magento 2 bug. See my answer. Or did it work for you? Actually I am using the latest beta, not the `develop` branch.

Comment: How it is working from admin ? I am working on magento master branch code.

Comment: Had the same error when running grunt  exec: mytheme (win7 xampp). Running CMD as admin sorted the issue :).

Comment: Disclaimer: Basically working - but there is still one issue in Magento 2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1619

The is a patch at

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/godban/8cb178f9a84ed85f1eac/raw/08692fc973adb4d5fa1eb8e57702c4a7d236658a/deployer_and_import_fix.patch

Comment: Are you running cmd command prompt run with administrator  privilege ? i am use windows system and i had face this issue in windows. cmd command prompt run with administrator privilege, i am success. try it and tell me next error.

Comment: Nope, but my permissions should be right, and I work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found how recreate symlinks:
use next command:
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --theme="{THEME_NAME}"
where {THEME_NAME} - is string, like Magento/blank

See docs here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-less-sass.html

Maybe you need to run grunt exec before that, I'm not sure.

But after that you can run grunt watch and it will work.