# Magento 2 Theme Development - grunt watch not detecting changes of custom LESS file

Tags: magento2, theme, less, static-content-deploy, grunt

We are running Magento 2 in version 2.3.1, but the error occurred in version 2.3.0 also. The situation is the following:

- we've created a custom theme which has **Magento/luma** theme as parent.
- according to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html we've installed node and grunt for theme LESS development.
- the grunt themes.js config of our custom child theme has **files:['css/styles-m', 'css/styles-l', 'css/style']** entries. (where 'styles-m' and  'styles-l' are files from the parent, and 'css/style' is our custom LESS file)
- our custom LESS file **style.less** is located in our custom **VENDOR/THEME/web/css/** folder and is also registered as `<css src="css/style.css" />` within **default_head_blocks.xml** of our theme.

Now the problem is, that executing commands **grunt clean:THEME**, **grunt exec:THEME**, **grunt less:THEME** and **grunt watch** will not create symlinked files within pub/static folder. Instead it copies the source stylesheets to the pub folder, and therefore **grunt watch** will not detect any changes.
Of course I researched and checked solutions like cleaning cache, rebuilding anything and deploying static content before running the grunt tasks. (e.g. [Magento 2 grunt exec does not actually create symlinks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85144/magento-2-grunt-exec-does-not-actually-create-symlinks) or [What are the Magento 2 Grunt commands? From deployment?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99839/what-are-the-magento-2-grunt-commands-from-deployment))

I also verified that there are **no external imports** within my custom style.less file. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1619#issuecomment-377472378) We're running under FreeBSD.

Sadly the Symlink is not created and therefore grunt does not detect changes of my custom 'style.less' file:
[image: symlink not created]

Do you have any idea why this happens, or did someone experience the same with m2? Thanks in advance for all your help!

**UPDATE 09.04.19:**

- I added source/_custom.less according to Chandras comment([Magento 2 Theme Development - grunt watch not detecting changes of custom LESS file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268867/magento-2-theme-development-grunt-watch-not-detecting-changes-of-custom-less-f/268895?noredirect=1#comment381608_268895))
- I added the _custom.less to default_head_blocks and themes.js configuration.
  The result is: the less file gets generated, but also not symlinked to the source file, therefore grunt watch still does not recognize any change.
  [image: generated less file without symlink]
  Anyone any idea?

Comment: u can also enable symlink form backend configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean the option "allow symlinks" under "shops" -> "configuration" -> "developer"? This option was already enabled.

Comment: okay, then you need to enable Developer mode.

Comment: developer mode is also already enabled :) some symlinks are generated, just the ones for my custom theme not.

Answer (score 7):

Please open the file:

**dev\tools\grunt\configs\local-themes.js**

```
module.exports = {
    company_base: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Company/Base',  // <--- name must match the folder structure of your theme
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    }
};
```

And check if the **name** matches your Theme folder (case sensitive!)

I faced the same problem as you, because my theme folder is:

> app\design\frontend\**Company\Base**\web\css\source_extend.less

but the name in the configuration was set to **company/base** instead of **Company/Base**

Then execute:

```
grunt refresh && grunt exec:your_theme && grunt less:your_theme && php bin/magento cache:flush full_page && grunt watch
```

**Note**: Replace `your_theme` with `company_base` in this example.

If it still does not work then you probably try to add css to **_extend.less** directly. This does not seem to work, you are only allowed to use this file for imports.

Comment: grunt refresh extremely helpful after 1000000 less changes

Comment: @Goldy It may work for you, try `grunt refresh && grunt watch`. As noted in some hard-to-find Magento wisdom here: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-frontend-workflow-step-by-step/, the `exec-> less`/ `refresh` stage has to be run **before** you can run watch. I should probably know why, but it works **shrugs**

Answer (score 1):

Go to the dev\tools\grunt\configs\themes.js file:

**Configure there your theme js just below luma:**

```
themename: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'yourvendor/themename',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l',     
        'css/yourcssfile',          
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

**Then run below commands serially:**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

grunt exec:themename

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

**Now run command:**

grunt watch

Comment: Hi Chandra! Thanks for your answer. Sadly it does not work, the Symlink's still not created and grunt does not detect changes when I update my custom 'style.less' file. (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd11Q.png)

Comment: If you want your custom less file, I suggest you other way:

Go to app\design\frontend\yourvendor\themename\web\css\source:

Add your _custom.less file.

Override _sources.less file in app\design\frontend\yourvendor\themename\web\css\source and add below line:
@import '_custom.less';

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do I have to add the _custom.less to themes.js or to default_head_blocks of my custom theme? Sadly grunt watch is still not working, and the website is not loading my _custom.less at all.

Comment: Hey Chandra! See my updated question for details.

Comment: No need to add in theme.js file or anywhere. Go to vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source and copy _sources.less file. put this file in to you theme directory app\design\frontend\yourvendor\themename\web\css\source and add below line: @import '_custom.less';

Comment: then run commands  'grunt exec:themename', 'grunt watch' and try to change in  _custom.less. it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Black is relevant, but I found out through [this article][1] that the order of grunt tasks is important.

Make sure you run it in this order:

```
grunt refresh; #this is a serial command of clean-> exec -> less
#now grunt should know what files to monitor, so use watch
grunt watch;
```

**N.B:** The above article advises you to run `grunt refresh` (or `grunt clean; grunt exec; grunt less`, whatever allows you manual compilation) after changing your theme fs structure (deleting/adding files etc.)
[1]: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-frontend-workflow-step-by-step/